# Есть ли способ присвоить вектору массив без копирования?

Tags: c++, vector, std

Хочу присвоить вектору массив, не перенося его в вектор поэлементно в цикле, а используя std::move. Такая возможность есть в классе стринг, возможно ли что то подобное в векторе?

Comment: а что хранится в массиве?

Comment: А почему сразу не записывать данные в вектор? Зачем вам сначала нужен с-массив?

Comment: может данные так приходят с сишной либы. Тогда просто `vector<...> x (array, array+Len);`

Comment: @KoVadim, так все равно ж копирование будет. Я так понимаю тс хочет мувнуть обычный кусок памяти в вектор

Comment: да. поэтому я и спрашиваю, что хранится в массиве. Если там int - то копия будет самое оптимальное. Если там коплексные объекты, для которых move может дать прирост - тогда другое дело

Comment: @KoVadim, а почему второй аргумент - указатель на первый элемент + длина, не понял его? Да, комплексные объекты и хотелось бы использовать мув семантику, это возможно?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы данные в памяти были в единственном экземпляре (т.е. указатель на данные в векторе адресовал данные в исходном массиве)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко - то нет. Но если копнуть глубже, то есть несколько различных вариантов.

Допустим, в массиве хранятся простые типы, для которых move на самом деле делает просто копирование - `int`, указатель, `std::pair`. В этом случае самым эффективным будет просто его скопировать

```
int * array = get_array();
vector<int> vec (array, array+length); // length - размер массива
```

Следующий случай. Массив хранит что то, что умеет эффективно перемещаться. Например, std::string.

```
const int LEN = 2;
std::string array[LEN] = {std::string("foo"), std::string("bar")};
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.resize(LEN);
std::move(array, array+LEN, vec.begin());
```

Возможно здесь можно лучше, но как по мне, resize портит все. Но если у Вас уже есть готовый вектор подходящего размера - вперед.

Потом внимательно посмотрел в документацию и понял, что есть куда проще и красивее способ (вывод - выглядит код криво - читай документацию)

```
const int LEN = 2;
std::string array[LEN] = {std::string("foo"), std::string("bar")};
std::vector<std::string> vec {
    std::make_move_iterator(array),
    std::make_move_iterator(array+LEN)
};
```

Если у Вас есть поддержка двадцатого стандарта, тогда можно использовать класс [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). Я не понимаю, как он не появился раньше.  Если стандарт новый не доступен, можно использовать его реализацию с [gsl::span](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) - обычно пару файлов подтянуть - не проблема.

Этот класс позволяет завернуть голый сишный массив в обертку и дальше использовать вектороподобный интерфейс. Конечно, о памяти нужно побеспокоиться отдельно. Но в этом случае накладные расходы минимальны.

Comment: У вектора есть конструктор, принимающий размер, а вообще можно просто `vec.reserve(LEN)` и `std::back_inserter`.